# Filtering results of a set of matches (Beyond filtering Union)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here's the scenario. I'm trying to create an inbox of the most recent (multi message) conversations between users in which the most recent message (sent OR received) has a brief preview in the listing.

(as an aside I'm aware of the post UNION filtering issue that's open: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725) but I'm not sure if my question is fully answered by that.

Let's imagine it displays like this:

---

User 1's inbox:

user03 - "hey hows it going I..."

user02 - "yo user 2, I saw wh..."

user04 - "did you know I foun..."

user26 - "dear user01 I just ..."

---

In the graph database conversations are represented with this relationship:

```
(:User)<-[s:SENDER]-(m:Message)-[r:RECEIVER]->(:User)
```

Matching this and ordering by m.created_at gets you conversations.

I can easily find messages between specific users and I can easily find all messages that include a given user such as in the following query (given a username of "brendanh":

```
MATCH (u:User)<-[s:SENDER]-(m:Message)-[r:RECEIVER]->(u2:User) 
WHERE (u.username = "brendanh") OR (u2.username = "brendanh")
RETURN  m.body, u.username as sender, u2.username as receiver ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
```

Obviously that previous query gets me ALL messages from or to "brendanh"

Example result rows:

```
body            sender        receiver

blah blah blah  brendanh      user2
foo foo foo     user3         brendanh
bar bar bar     user2         brendanh
test test       brendanh      user4
i do not know   user3         brendan
```

Where as what I want is this:

```
body            sender        receiver

blah blah blah  brendanh      user2
foo foo foo     user3         brendanh
test test       brendanh      user4
```

I can get *just* a set of unique conversational participants with the following:

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'brendanh'})<-[]-(m:Message)-[]->(u2:User) 
return distinct(u2.username)
```

But it's not like I can take that list of single usernames and do a "For" match on it returning the first message match for each. (Within the cypher query I mean)

I could collect that list of conversational participants (I'm running this in Golang) and then run a query to the graphdb for each individual result but that seems messy.

I've tried using UNWIND and a list of the usernames from that previously described query that listed conversational partners but again I get every message not just the first message for each user.

Is there something extremely obvious I'm missing here?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

P.S. Ideally I'd like to limit the number of responses such that if I want to display only the first ten results assuming the user has >10 conversations but that's less important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so easy to understand what you want, but I think I got it.

You want each partner to only occur once in the list with their first? message.

Perhaps like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)<-[r:SENDER|:RECEIVER]-(m:Message)-[:SENDER|:RECEIVER]->(u2:User) 
WHERE (u.username = "brendanh")
WITH u2,m,type(r) as action ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
WITH u2,head(collect({type:type(r), msg: m})) as conv
RETURN  u2.username, conv.msg.body, conv.type
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of "r not defined" 

I'm unfamiliar with type() and I'm not seeing it in the docs (Though perhaps I'm not searching in the right place)
Edit:
oh! I think you meant this:

`WITH u2,head(collect({type:action, msg: m})) as conv`
And I think this is working! FANTASTIC. Thank you!